# How to check instance of parameters in function?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have to different interface

```
interface Vehicle {
// data about vehicle
}

interface Package {
// data about package
}
```

I have a component that in it's props can receive either of them (and maybe more in the future),
so I created props interface as such:

```
interface Props<T> {
  modalVisible: boolean,
  selectableData: T[],
  currentlySelectedIndex: number,
  onSelect: (selection: T) => void,
  onBackPressed: () => void
}
```

In my component I have a `FlatList` that receives the `selectableData` and a `renderItem` function that like this:

```
   <FlatList
      data={selectableData}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      style={{ maxHeight: 251 }}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <FlatListItemSeparator separatorStyle= 
      {styles.itemSeparator} />}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} />

  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<Vehicle | Package> = ({ item }) => (
    <ModalSelectionItem
      topText={ item instance Vehicle ? 'a' : 'b'}
    />
  );
```

I want to render different text in the `FlatList` based on type that was passed, how can I check what type of I have? I tried to use both `instanceof` and `typeof` but none of them seems to work

Comment: You can't because that type information isn't bound to the objects. If you want to check for a specific instance(with `instanceof/typeof`) you would have to use classes and create instances of the class. You could add a type field to the interface struct and use that field to determine the type

Answer (score 2):

The way Typescript works, is that it checks your code at the compile time, after the code is compiled, it's just plain javascript, so `Interface` doesn't exist at runtime.
There are two ways to do it.

1. Use classes, then you can use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator to check with which class you are working.
2. Easier, have a `type`(`string` or `enum`) property on your object (interface) and check that.

Comment: Added the possibility to use a enum to prevent magic strings in Edit. An enum will be transpiled to a plain object and will keep working at runtime with javascript

Comment: The strings don't have to be magic if they are pre-determined. `type: 'a' | 'b'| 'c '`. Now only those three values are allowed.